# How will the OSX Lion upgrade affect my Win 7 bootcamp setup?

Tags: windows, bootcamp, macos

And what are things to watch out for based on previous upgrades?

Comment: Lion questions are currently off-topic.

Comment: Seems like moderators have their hands full closing all of the Lion questions - I feel for you.

Comment: @bckbck: I asked a question over on meta about what to do about these because I hadn't heard that myself. The early opinion about these questions is that they will *not* be opened upon Lion's release. Putting aside the fact that there are too many to reopen now, a lot might have changed between beta and release to keep these relevant, and a lot of the questions will be answered on their own upon release. I think we'll be just cutting our losses and leaving closed questions alone. That policy may change, but I doubt it.

Comment: @Phillip: ok, noted.

Comment: Why not ask the question again. Asking people what changes happened between Leopard and Snow Leopard would be a great question. If people take some of that advice to heart for tomorrow, the discussion is about something that actually shipped and isn't directly asking people to break their word if they signed an NDA.

Comment: Being one of the people that would want an answer to this particular question, I have to agree with the reasoning behind closing it. In 6 months time, this question will have little to no meaning as there will be plenty of sites that outline the process of updating, and thus it would be closed as "too localized", ie. only relevant for a specific period of time or for a specific version. @Odinuff's answer bears promise though that the upgrade will be painless, but I agree that until someone *actually* upgrades, we won't know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

No, the Lion upgrade will only affect the partitioned part of your hard drive housing Mac OS.

Edit:

It will also install a small partition housing, basically, the installer of Mac OS. This is so that if your installation ever fails or something like that you can always reinstall.